# Is there a nice notation for second derivative similar to bilinear form?

Tags: derivatives, tensors, bilinear-form

I want to write down this thing in a matrix-ish way:

$$
A_{ij} = \alpha\ v\nabla_i\nabla_ju + \beta\ (\nabla_i v)(\nabla_j u) + \gamma\  (\nabla_j v) (\nabla_i u) + \delta\ u\nabla_i\nabla_jv
$$

The closest form I come up with:
$$
  A_{ij} = \pmatrix{v\nabla_i\\\nabla_iv}^T
           \pmatrix{\gamma& \delta\\\alpha& \beta}
           \pmatrix{u\nabla_j\\\nabla_ju} = \\
       \underbrace{\alpha\ v\nabla_i \nabla_j u +
       \beta\  (\nabla_iv)(\nabla_ju)}_{\text{nice}} + 
       \underbrace{\gamma\ v(\nabla_iu)\nabla_j +
       \delta\ (\nabla_iv)u\nabla_j}_{\text{nonsense}}
$$

Could you suggest a notation that reflect the similarity to bilinear form?